# Adding an ODBC connection using Powershell, plus UID and PWD

Tags: odbc, powershell-4.0

I'm having difficulty find a way to get User based ODBC connections to load a default username and password across my user base. I know it's awful and have asked the DBA to sort themselves out, for in the interim we're looking at facilitating this request.

In the script as below I can't run the "PWD" and "UID" variables through because: *Add-OdbcDsn : Attempt to set the {UID or PWD} key of a DSN. These keys should not be stored in the registry for
security reason. Provide the credential information at runtime via SQLDriverConnect, SQLConnect or SQLBrowseConnect.
At line:19 char:11*

Aside from a mad rush to Windows NT auth are there any options for me? most of what I've found online doesn't work when I try it and I'm sadly running out of ideas. Any help would be most appreciated.

SCRIPT BELOW:

#Running the IF statement checks to the see if an ODBC connection is present#

if ( (Get-OdbcDsn -Name "NAME" -DsnType "User" -Platform 64-Bit -ErrorAction Ignore) -ne $null)

#This then loads a code-bock which runs after the IF statement, which writes the output "Connection Present"#

{

Write-Output "Connection Present"

}

#Otherwise it runs ELSE#

else

{

$NewDsn = Add-OdbcDsn -Name "NAME" -DriverName "SQL Server" -DsnType "User" -SetPropertyValue @("Description=** ***", "Server=SERVER", "Trusted_Connection=Yes", "Database=DATABASE") -Platform 64-Bit -PassThru

}

#This creates the ODBC connection as above#

P.S. I've read that SQL Server is practically older than I am, I'm in the process of getting the latest driver deployed via InTune once that's packaged.

Comment: To add to this, I have found that setting "Trusted_Connection=No" allows me to connect via SQL but am still unable to specify the UID or PWD, I totes get this is for security reasons but it is still quite difficult to accept the argument that it's the user's job to fill that in.